# How to determine day, month, and year as int in iOS

Tags: ios, int, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nsdatecomponents

I want to determine day, month, and year of current date in iOS. I found this after a search on the net:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:date];
NSInteger Day = [components day];
NSInteger month = [components month];
NSInteger year = [components year];
```

This code shows the day correct, but the year and month is not showing as it should be. It shows some digits like 2147483647. I could not find a solution so please help me correct the code I found, or write some new code which does what I need.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This line is the problem:

```
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:date];
```

It should be

```
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:date];
```

Comment: Thanks SOSBORN i appreciate your help